# Responsive custom div table

Tags: html, css, html-table, bootstrap-4, responsive

I had to make div table, because I didn't see a way to do it with a bootstrap table element.

Here is image:

[image]

Here is the code:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row border-top bg-primary pt-3 pb-0 mt-5">
      <div class="col-12">
        <p class="text-white"><b>Lorem ipsum</b></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row border-left border-right text-center">
      <div class="col-8 pt-3 pb-0 border-right">
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4 pt-3 pb-0">
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row border text-center">
      <div class="col-10">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col pt-3 pb-0 border-right">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col pt-3 pb-0 border-right">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col pt-3 pb-0 border-right">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col pt-3 pb-0 border-right">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col pt-3 pb-0 border-right">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row border-top">
          <div class="col bg-primary-dark pt-3 pb-0" style="width: 80%; flex-basis: unset;">
            <p class="text-white"><b>Lorem ipsum</b></p>
            <p class="text-white">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="col border-right" style="width: 20%; flex-basis: unset;"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row border-top">
          <div class="col border-right" style="width: 20%; flex-basis: unset;"></div>
          <div class="col bg-info-dark pt-3 pb-0 border-right" style="width: 80%; flex-basis: unset;">
            <p class="text-white"><b>Lorem ipsum</b></p>
            <p class="text-white">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-2 pt-3">
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Now I want this to be responsive. Horizontal scroll, or any other way, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

I would recommend that you post more detail on how you have so far attempted to solve the issue you're facing. We are here to help but not to simply do the entire task for you without an attempt by yourself because you won't learn that way.

Comment: Try wraping all of it in div and add style="overflow-x:auto;" to that div, also it is possible to do it with table tag

Comment: I also just added boostrap as an *external resource* in your snippet so that Bootstrap loads in. You could also add your CSS to this to make it a 1:1 replication of whats on your screen. Please also avoid adding pictures of what can easily be demonstrated by your code in a snippet because in lets say 2 years time when a user comes to this post for the same issue, the image may not exist anymore... This is covered in the link I posted in my first comment.

Answer (score 0):

The class col in bootstrap will divide the row into amount of col elements you added.To make it responsive specify width of element for each screen type, using such classes as col-sm-12 (full width on small devices), col-md-6 (two column grid for medium screens) etc. Don't forget, bootstrap is mobile first.